# Duda con createElement('div') por id

Tags: javascript

Estoy desarrollando un portfolio y en el siguiente código veréis que recojo la información de un fichero *.json*, hasta aquí no hay ningún problema. Para los que no utilizáis *fetch*, os dejo la información aquí.

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Código:

```
targetAbout.addEventListener('click', () => {
    document.querySelector('#row').style.display = 'block';
    console.log('Mostrado: ' + targetAbout + hora());
});

// Mostramos contenido por medio de ajax y json.
var respuestaHTML = document.querySelector('#elem');
var tpl = '';

fetch('json/productos.json', {mode: 'no-cors'})
  .then((response) => {
     return response.json()
  })
  .then((category) => {
     category.forEach((elem) => {
        tpl += '<img src="' + elem.thumbnailUrl + '"/>'
         + '<article class="elem-title"><p>' + elem.title + '</p></article>';
     });
     respuestaHTML.innerHTML = tpl;
   }).catch((err) => {
     console.log('Ha fallado: ' + err);
   });
```

Recupero la información sin problema y lo muestra en un `<div>` pero mi duda es:

¿Si lo que quiero es que cada vez que recoja los datos de un documento *.json* lo muestre en un `div` con el mismo id del primero? Es decir que cree un elemento cada vez que tenga que mostrar información.

El ID sería **elem**:

```
<section id="row">
     <article id="elem">
     </article>
</section>
```

¿Debería de hacer uso de createElementById? ¿Cómo hago para que sea en un `div` con un determinado id?

Agradecería que fuese en Javascript, no usando algún frameworks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

La función `createElementById` no existe, en su lugar usa [`createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement). Este **no** soporta la sintáxis de jquery `$('<div id="elem"></div>')`, en su lugar la sintaxis es:

```
var referencia = document.createElement('tagName');
```

donde tagName es `'div'`, `'span'`, `'img'`, etc.

Luego manipulas la referencia y modificas sus atributos (el id es uno de ellos).

```js
// Creas el elemento
var elem = document.createElement('div');
// Modificas los atributos
elem.id = "elem";
// Lo insertas en el DOM
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
parent.appendChild(elem);
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
#elem {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
</div>
```

Tener ids repetidos no es html válido por lo que te recomiendo que si tienes varios del mismo tipo uses clases en su lugar

```js
// Creas el elemento
var elem = document.createElement('div');
// Agregas una clase
elem.classList.add('elem');
// Lo insertas en el DOM
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
parent.appendChild(elem);
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
.elem {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
</div>
```

Podrías eliminar el anterior antes de agregar uno nuevo en caso que si lo necesites por id

```js
// Buscas el elemento anterior
var old = document.getElementById('elem');
if (old !== null) {
  // Si existe lo eliminas
  old.remove();
}

// Creas el elemento
var elem = document.createElement('div');
// Modificas el id
elem.id = "elem";
// Lo insertas en el DOM
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
parent.appendChild(elem);
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
#elem {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
  <div id="elem"></div>
</div>
```

Si manipulas directamente el padre puedes agregar varios elementos usando la propiedad [innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) y puedes especificar elementos y atributos directamente en una cadena de caracteres.

```
padre.innerHTML = '<div id="elem"></div>';
```

Esto funciona porque el navegador parsea esta cadena y la convierte a elementos por ti. Usualmente es más recomendable esta vía por la cantidad de líneas de código que genera la creación y configuración manual de elementos. En el ejemplo uso clases porque como te dije anteriormente no debes tener ids repetidos.

```js
// Creas el elemento
var parent = document.getElementById('parent');
// Creas una variable que representa el contenido del elemento
var contents = '';
var data = ['e1', 'e2', 'e3'];
for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
  contents += '<div class="elem">' + data[i] + '</div>';
}
// Reemplazas su contenido completamente
parent.innerHTML = contents;
```

```css
#parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: red;
}
.elem {
  background-color: blue;
  margin: 10px;
  height: 100%;
  color: white;
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent">
</div>
```

Comment: La función createElementById no existe => (Si, fue una errata por culpa del autocompletado del editor). Tu código es correcto, pero no se si me di a entender, supongamos que en una fila se permiten 4 elementos, cada uno con un contenido,  todos con el mismo diseño si agrego mas datos a un archivo json, deberá de mostrar automáticamente un div igual que los otros, es ahí donde esta mi problema, probé tu código y como te dije mas arriba solventa mi duda de como crear elementos, pero no asignarles contenido dinámico.

Comment: @UnderZero_- Agregué un ejemplo usando innerHTML que te permite crear cualquier cantidad de elementos dinámicos. Esta variante es mucho mas simple que usar createElement. No la puse al principio ya que en tu código ya la empleabas por lo que asumí que conocias los detalles de su uso. Saludos

Comment: Soy un desastre, lo lógico era usar un bucle for, no se en que estaba pensando. Genial exposición, es la respuesta que buscaba.

Answer (score 1):

Yo utilizaría con clases en lugar de ids. Si hay una serie de elementos `.elm`, obtengo el que está vacío para mostrar allí la data, si no, creo uno nuevo con la misma clase.

```
function findEmptyElm() {
  const elms = document.querySelectorAll('.elm');
  elms.foEach((elm)=> {
    if(elm.innerText === '') {
      return elm;
    }
  });
  // si ya todos están disponibles
  const elm = document.createElement('article');
  elm.classList.add('elm');
  document.querySelector('.row').appendChild(elm);
  retun elm;
}

function fetchArticles() {
  // esto de preferencia al principio
  let elm = findEmptyElm();
  /* Tu código */
}
```